# Clickhouse doesn't use skip index with Final modifer in query

Tags: indexing, clickhouse

I have Added a skip index on a field (status_id) in clickhouse. It is used and working when I use my query as below:

```
EXPLAIN INDEXES=1
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM mytable WHERE 
created_date='2022-10-05' and status_id=123;
```

The result:

```
Expression ((Projection + Before ORDER BY))
  Aggregating
    Expression (Before GROUP BY)
      Filter (WHERE)
        SettingQuotaAndLimits (Set limits and quota after reading from storage)
          ReadFromMergeTree
          Indexes:
            MinMax
              Keys: 
                created_date
              Condition: (created_date in [19270, 19270])
              Parts: 3/138
              Granules: 346/8840
            Partition
              Keys: 
                toYYYYMM(created_date)
              Condition: (toYYYYMM(created_date) in [202210, 202210])
              Parts: 3/3
              Granules: 346/346
            PrimaryKey
              Condition: true
              Parts: 3/3
              Granules: 346/346
            Skip
              Name: status_index
              Description: set GRANULARITY 1
              Parts: 3/3
              Granules: 14/346
```

But when I use the `final` modifier, the skip index is not used anymore:

```
EXPLAIN INDEXES=1
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM mytable FINAL WHERE 
created_date='2022-10-05' and status_id=123;
```

The result:

```
Expression ((Projection + Before ORDER BY))
  Aggregating
    Expression (Before GROUP BY)
      Filter (WHERE)
        SettingQuotaAndLimits (Set limits and quota after reading from storage)
          ReadFromMergeTree
          Indexes:
            MinMax
              Keys: 
                created_date
              Condition: (created_date in [19270, 19270])
              Parts: 3/136
              Granules: 346/8838
            Partition
              Keys: 
                toYYYYMM(created_date)
              Condition: (toYYYYMM(created_date) in [202210, 202210])
              Parts: 3/3
              Granules: 346/346
            PrimaryKey
              Condition: true
              Parts: 3/3
              Granules: 346/346
```

I couldn't find anything in the documentation that Final keyword would prevent clickhouse from utilizing skip indexes. So I'm wondering what is wrong.

Clickhouse Version: 22.3.15.33

Table Engine: Replacing Merge Tree

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it's deliberately otherwise you will get an incorrect result https://github.com/ClickHouse/ClickHouse/pull/34243

there is a setting: `use_skip_indexes_if_final`

It is impossible to get the correct result in general if one use SKIP INDEX and FINAL. SKIP INDEX works before FINAL and filters out FINAL rows.

imagine you have a table

```
key   | version      | some_column_which_should_calculated_during_the_final 
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
1     |     1        | true
1     |     2        | false
```

`select * from .... FINAL where some_column_which_should_calculated_during_the_final=true` should return **zero rows**. Because the final row version=2 is = false

But if you use skip index it will return `1  |  1  | true` because SKIP index filters out `version=2`, then final will evaluate 1 row instead of 2

Pipeline

1. Partition Pruning
2. Primary index
3. Skip index / PREWHERE
4. FINAL
5. WHERE

so the same issue with Partition Pruning (if you use some_column_which_should_calculated_during_the_final in PARITION BY)